# Type mismatch error in VBA when adding data to textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `TextBox` and a `ListBox` with a list of various cities being populated from an Excel file

Now each city has one of two options: either within territory or outside. I want that option to be shown in **`textBox`**

I tried something like this :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

TextBox2.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Text,Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:C"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

But am getting error stating that :

> Run Time Error 2147352571 (80020005) . Could not set Value property. Type mismatch.

My excel file is something like this :

[image]

Comment: Does ListBox is placed on UserForm? How do you load data into it?

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes it is placed on Userform and I load by setting its Rowsource to the name from excel file

Comment: Does Listbox displays entire range (name, city, territory)?

Comment: If `Application.VLookup` does not find the lookup value, it returns the `#N/A` error. `TextBox2.Value` cannot become an error value.

Comment: @MaciejLos No. It has only city

Comment: @AxelRichter So what can be reason for it ?

Comment: @ho_dareago, what kind of result you do excpect when user select `Clarston` city? This city is repeated 3 times, so... when you're using VLookup function to get territory, you'll get `within territory` 3 times. You can not aply array to Text property of TextBox.

Comment: @MaciejLos I removed multiple entries. Still same error

Comment: @MaciejLos In textbox the corresponding terroirtary value should be displayed. If user selects Clarston then it should display WITHIN TERROITARY on click of button

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. Are you sure you are working on the correct objects? Also make sure that something is selected in the `ListBox1`, else you will get that value.

Answer (score 0):

Let say your data are stored in `Sheet1`. You want to bind these data to `ListBox1` on `UserForm`. I'd suggest to use custom function to load data instead of binding data via using `RowSource` property. In this case i'd suggest to use [Dictionary](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234) to avoid duplicates.

See:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim d As Dictionary
Dim aKey As Variant

Set d = GetDistinctCitiesAndTerritories
For Each aKey In d.Keys
    With Me.ListBox1
        .AddItem ""
        .Column(0, .ListCount - 1) = aKey
        .Column(1, .ListCount - 1) = d.Item(aKey)
    End With
Next
End Sub

'needs reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime!
Function GetDistinctCitiesAndTerritories() As Dictionary

Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim dict As Dictionary
Dim i As Integer

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set dict = New Dictionary

i = 2
Do While wsh.Range("A" & i) <> ""
    If Not dict.Exists(wsh.Range("B" & i)) Then dict.Add wsh.Range("B" & i), wsh.Range("C" & i)
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set GetDistinctCitiesAndTerritories = dict

End Function
```

After that, when user clicks on `ListBox`, `city` and `territory` are displayed in corresponding textboxes.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Me.TextBoxCity = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
Me.TextBoxTerritory = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)

End Sub
```

Note: code was written straight from the head, so it can contains errors!

Comment: -@MaciejLos--why would you supply code, if you don't know if it works? Did you test it first before supplying it as an answer?

Comment: @Davesexcel, no i haven't test it. I'm almost sure it have to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you aren't checking to see to see if the call to Application.VLookup succeeded.  Most values returned can be successfully cast to a String - with one important exception:  If the VLookup returns an error, for example it doesn't find Me.ListBox1.Text - it can't cast the Variant returned directly.

This should demonstrate:

```
Private Sub ReturnsOfVLookup()

    Dim works As Variant, doesnt As String

    works = Application.VLookup("Something not found", _
                                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:C"), 2, False)
    Debug.Print works

    On Error Resume Next
    doesnt = Application.VLookup("Something not found", _
                                 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:C"), 2, False)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Description
    Else
        Debug.Print doesnt  'We won't be going here...  ;-)
    End If

End Sub
```